# Regex Pattern in Python for special charaters

Tags: python, regex, string

I asked a similar question a few days ago on here and it was great help! A new challenge I wanted build is to further develop the regex pattern to look for specific formats in this iteration, and I thought I have solved it using regex 101 to build/test a regex code but when applied in Python received 'pattern contain no group'. Below is a test df, and a image of what the results should be like/code that was provided via StackOverflow that worked with digits only.

```
       
df = pd.DataFrame([["{1} | | Had a Greeter welcome clients {1.0}     | | Take measures to ensure a safe and organized distribution {1.000}         | | Protected confidentiality of clients (on social media, pictures, in conversation, own congregation members receiving assistance, etc.)",
                    "{1.00}  | | Chairs for clients to sit in while waiting {1.0000}     | | Take measures to ensure a safe and organized distribution"],
                   ["{1  } | Financial literacy/budgeting {1   } | | Monetary/Bill Support {1}    | | Mental Health Services/Counseling",
                    "{1}| | Clothing Assistance {1       }  | | Healthcare {1}    | | Mental Health Services/Counseling {1}     | | Spiritual Support {1}      | | Job Skills Training"]
                    ] , columns = ['CF1', 'CF2'])
```

[image: Result]

Here is the iteration code that worked digits only. I changed the pattern search with my new regex pattern and it did not work.

Original code: `(df.stack().str.extractall('(\d+)')[0] .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())`

New Code (Failed to recognize pattern): `(df.stack().str.extractall(r'(?<=\{)[\d+\.\ ]+(?=\})')[0].astype(int) .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())`

**In the test df you will see I want to only capture the numbers between "{}" and there's a mixture of decimals and spaces following the number I want to capture and sum. The new pattern did not work in application so any help would be great! **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `(?<=\{)[\d+\.\ ]+(?=\})` regex contains no capturing groups while [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) requires at least one capturing group to output a value.

You need to use

```py
(df.stack().str.extractall(r'\{\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*}')[0].astype(float) .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())
```

Output:

```
   CF1  CF2
0  3.0  2.0
1  3.0  5.0
```

The `\{\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*}` regex matches

- `\{` - a `{` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1 (note this group captured value will be the output of the `extractall` method, it requires at least one capturing group): one or more digits, and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `}` -  a `}` char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PD0eM4/1).

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor! This works perfectly! I'm going to have to investigate why my original regex code did not work in application

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer See the top of my answer. Also, `(?<=\{)[\d+\.\ ]+(?=\})` just matches one or more `+`, `.`, spaces or digits immediately after `{` and immediately before `}`. So, it could even "catch" `...` in `{...}`.

Comment: @Witkor. This is a long shot since it's been a while since you last spoke but this solution worked! However, I was hoping to improve my results by changing that group by based on two columns and ran into an issue where it would not recognize the column names. What changes are required in that groupby statement you provided. My columns are ['subID', 'Labels'].

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer Sorry to answer that late, but it seems you want `df2 = df[['subID', 'Labels']]` and then `(df2.stack().str.extractall(r'\{\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*}')[0].astype(float) .groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\{([\d.]+)\}'`:

```
(df.stack().str.extractall(r'\{([\d.]+)\}')[0]
   .astype(float).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())
```

output:

```
   CF1  CF2
0  3.0  2.0
1  1.0  4.0
```

###### as int only:

```
(df.stack().str.extractall(r'\{(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?\}')[0]
   .astype(int).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack())
```

output:

```
   CF1  CF2
0    3    2
1    1    4
```

Comment: Thank you again @Mozay! Could you happen to explain why the format is different than what worked in Regex 101? Also is it possible to include space since some of the "{1   }" have spaces as a different type of format

Comment: Yes, you can add `\s*` -> `'\{(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?\s*\}'`

Comment: This is a long shot since it's been a while since you last spoke but you've helped me on previous regex problems such as this. I was hoping to improve my results by changing that group by based on two columns in the original df and ran into an issue where it would not recognize the column names. What changes are required in that groupby statement? My columns are ['subID', 'Labels'].